# Add an additional mailboxe in Outlook

Tags: .net, vba, outlook

So we have Office 365 based Outlook accounts and sometimes have to add additional mailboxes like it's done here :
[image: example]

But I have to do it without using the GUI method, by command line, developing something in VB.NET, C# or VBA. I don't have access to the admin side of the server so I can't use powershell commands there.

I tried using VBA but didn't got what I wanted, also using PRF files with no results. I pretty sure this can be done, either way using VB.NET or C#

I'll be happy to get even a little hint on how to achieve this.

**EDIT :** 
So I found how to list every mailboxes using the "Stores" and how to add a new store by .pst file "AddStore".

But still didn't figured out how add a simple Microsoft Exchange mailbox. Seems that with Outlook Redemption is possible but for some internal reasons I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook Object Model does not expose that functionality. You can either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) to add a properly configured instance of the `"EMSDelegate"` MAPI service, or use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) - it exposes [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).[Stores](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostores.htm).`AddDelegateExchangeMailBoxStore` method.

Comment: Yes, Redemption can do the job but I don't want to have the popup of the free version and I don't want to pay 300 bucks for just one or two method. But I repeat, Redemption is still a very good library. I'll try it with Extended MAPI. Thanks!